# Google analytics tracking on ajax form within a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-analytics, modal-dialog

I realize similar posts have addressed this issue, however, the additional element of the modal in addition to ajax does not seem to have been addressed and I believe this is my issue. So, I have a modal form on my website. The button for the form is within the header. I am trying to get google analytics to track when the form has been submitted.

See Ajax here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var f = $('#modalForm');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "mail/modalFormSubmit.php",
      success: function(){
        $('form').hide();
        $("#modalSignup").html("<p><i class='fa fa-check'></i> Thank you for contacting us!</p>");  
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Goal', 'submit', 'Modal Submit']);             
      },
      data: f.serialize()
    });
});     
});
```

I've added the GA tracking code within the model at this time, when I insert it directly into the header I simply get false positives from other pages on the site:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Quality Products and Solutions</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
     <form id="modalForm" name="modalForm" method="post" action="">
                <label>Name <span class="color-red">*</span></label>
                <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-0">
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>                
                </div>

                <label>Email <span class="color-red">*</span></label>
                <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-0">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>                
                </div>

                     <label>City <span class="color-red">*</span></label>
                <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-0">
                        <input type="text" name="city" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>                
                </div>

                <label>State <span class="color-red">*</span></label>
                <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-0">
                        <input type="text" name="state" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>                
                </div>

                <label>Phone Number </label>
                <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-0">
                        <input type="tel" name="tel" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>                
                </div>

                <label>Message <span class="color-red">*</span></label>
                <div class="row margin-bottom-20">
                    <div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-0">
                        <textarea rows="8" name="message" class="form-control" required></textarea>
                    </div>                
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn-u">Send Message</button>


            </form>
        <div id="modalSignup"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'xxxxxx']); removed for Stack overflow submittal
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
                    })();
        </script>   


  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

I'm sure I don't even need the tracking code within the modal but I'm trying as many variables as I can. My apologies again if this is redundant but I can not find anything on the site that addresses this specific issue.

Comment: The tracking code should be right after the start of the `<body>` tag. Having `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);` at the start of `<body>` and in the modal will cause 2 page view's to be recorded (your false positives?). As for submitting the form and tracking the event, that looks correct to me. The important thing is to have the tracking code once and at the start of the `<body>` tag. Then you just need the `_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Goal', 'submit', 'Modal Submit']);` code as it already is in the success of your form submit.

Comment: What if I simply keep the tracking code in the modal but remove the `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);` from it? Wouldn't that allow it to track without pushing the pageview to GA?

Comment: That would be redundant. As per Google Analytics **Add the tracking code to each template page immediately after the opening <body> tag:**. So, you should have it in that location and that location only. Then you can use _gaq.push to send page views or whatever events you want.

Answer (score 0):

The code and logic *look* correct. Here are a couple thoughts:
1. Are you sure the success function is firing when the form submits?
2. Where is the modal coming from, is it on the page already and gets hidden/shown or is it a loaded remotely? If the latter, it may not know about the variables set in the parent page.
3. _gaq  may not be defined when the callback on the form runs. Have you checked for errors in the console or set a breakpoint in the success function to see what is happening?

Comment: 1. The success function is firing and the form submits to email. You can see the form here [link](http://rocktred.com/index.php) currently it only submits to myself. 2. The modal is in the header and appears upon the click of the 'Request a Quote' button. _gaq should be defined within the tracking code which I have implemented above where the ajax is called. Would it matter that _gaq has not been defined within the AJAX call?

Comment: Looked at the site and submitted a test form, the success function is firing and _gaq is defined. However, I suspect the problem is with how Google Analytics is set up on the page. The newer ga('send', 'pageview') AND the older _gaq.push('_trackPageview') is also used with the same account number. Are you getting double page views? I would try using ga('send', 'event', 'Goal', 'submit', 'Modal Submit'); I'm not certain on that syntax.